# cannot enter into an if block - java

Tags: java

The program is suppose to check if a string is consecutive including string such as zab and 901234. I wrote and exception to each so I can skip over 90 or za if they appear. Unfortunately I can't seem to get into the if block of code... I'm not sure why. If someone can help me get into this 901 it would be much appreciated.

```
   for (int i=0; i<s.length()-1; i++){
        if (s.charAt(i) == 9 && s.charAt(i + 1) == 0) {
            System.out.println("in");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember, integers get converted to characters through the ASCII table, so you want the `characters` `'9'` and `'0'`

Your original code was actually looking for the `null` (0) and `backspace` (9) characters. More info on the ASCII table here: [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

```
for (int i=0; i<s.length()-1; i++){
    if (s.charAt(i) == '9' && s.charAt(i + 1) == '0') {
        System.out.println("in");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to test for charachers:

```
if (s.charAt(i) == '9' && s.charAt(i + 1) == '0') {
```